# How to Mounting RAID0 EBS Volumes after reboot on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, raid, mdadm, amazon-ebs, amazon-linux

I've already attached two volumes to my EC2 instance and configured RAID0 for them. After a reboot, the volumes didn't re-attach.  I thought I had configured them to attach on reboot in `fstab` but they didn't attach.

Here's the output from `lsblk`:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk  
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part  /
xvdf    202:80   0   1T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0   2T  0 raid0 
xvdg    202:96   0  25G  0 disk  /journal
xvdh    202:112  0  50G  0 disk  /log
xvdi    202:128  0   1T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0   2T  0 raid0
```

But if I run `df -h`, `xvdf` and `xvdi` aren't there:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.4G  6.3G  18% /
devtmpfs         15G   80K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdg        25G   45M   24G   1% /journal
/dev/xvdh        50G   53M   47G   1% /log
```

Where did I go wrong? I'm using **Amazon Linux**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to reference the volume as `/dev/md127` in `fstab`.

Comment: http://www.n2ws.com/how-to-guides/connect-aws-ebs-volume-another-instance.html helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply mount "**md127**" to any folder. You can do that by below command.

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/md0 /opt
```

here I have mounted "**md127**" to **/opt/** folder

Comment: But that has to be done after every reboot, it's better to add a line to `/etc/fstab`.